# How to find all details from three different tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three different tables in sql. Following is table structure.

```
Table1:
pId - primary key
pName

Table2:
sId - primary key
sName
pId- foreign key

Table3:
gId primary key
gName 
sId - Foreign key
```

The relationship between table1 and table2 is 1 to many and table2 to table3 is again 1 to many.

Now I want all data from table2 and table3 for each of pId in table1.

I tried a following query:

```
 select  p.pId, p.pName, s.sId, s.sName, g.gId, g.gName
 from    table1 as p,
         table2 as s,
         table3 as g
 where   p.pId=s.pId AND s.sId=g.sId
 group by p.pId;
```

Sample data for table1:

```
pId      pName
1         p1
2         p2
```

Sample data for table2:

```
sId        sName  pId
11         s1     1
12         s1     2
```

Sample data for table3:

```
sId     gId       gName
11      111       g1
11      112       g2
```

I want output something like following:

```
[{pId:1,
  pname:p1,
  sub:[{
      sId:11,
      sName:s1,
      grades:[{
             gId:111,
             gName:g1
             },{
             gId:112,
             gName:g2
             }]
     }]
 },
 pId:1,
  pname:p1,
  sub:[{
      sId:12,
      sName:s2,
      grades:[]
     }]
 }]
```

Json structure is just for understanding.

Can anybody provide me some help/hint so that I can get mentioned output?

Comment: strip off the group by

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are really using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired output in *SQL* format, i.e. as tables.

Comment: What do you mean by "Json structure is just for understanding"? Are you saying you don't actually want JSON output? Note that relational database generally work in rows and columns. While some RDBMS's might provide ways to convert to/from XML or JSON, it's not the natural way of using the tools.

Comment: @CraigYoung I am new to sql so I mention the output I want in Json format. I am not expecting export output as a Json.

Comment: if you are not expecting Json format, please provide the output in table format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current select statement should raise an error, since when using group by, only columns that exists in the group by clause or in an aggrigation function can exist in the select clause as well.

The correct query is very much like the one you posted, just without the group by and with proper, explicit joins (implicit joins are outdated for over 20 years now), and turning these joins to left joins:

```
SELECT p.pId, p.pName, s.sId, s.sName, g.gId, g.gName
FROM table1 as p,
LEFT JOIN table2 as s ON p.pId=s.pId
LEFT JOIN table3 as g ON s.sId=g.sId
```

This should get you the following output:

```
pId  pName  sId  sName  gId  gName
1    p1     11   s1     111  g1
1    p1     11   s1     112  g2
2    p2     12   s1     null null
```

Answer (score 1):

Your existing query would be fine provided you delete the `GROUP BY` part. However, I strongly recommend you rather use explicit `JOIN` clauses within your `FROM` clause. It makes it easier to: differentiate join conditions from filter conditions; to spot mistakes in your joins; clearer to read the kind of join used (INNER or LEFT/RIGHT/FULL OUTER).

E.g.

```
select  p.pId, p.pName, s.sId, s.sName, g.gId, g.gName
from    table1 as p
        inner join table2 as s ON
            s.pId = p.pId
        inner join table3 as g ON
            g.sId = s.sId
```

This will produce the following table:

```
pId      pName     sId     sName   gId    gName
1        p1        11      s1      111    g1
1        p1        11      s1      112    g2
```

Alternatively you can replace the `inner join`s with `left outer join`s to observe the following changes in output:

```
pId      pName     sId     sName   gId    gName
1        p1        11      s1      111    g1
1        p1        11      s1      112    g2
2        p2        12      s1      NULL   NULL
```

The differences are as follows:

- `inner join` requires matches on both sides of the join. So because table3 doesn't have a match for `sId=12` in table2, it's excluded.
- Similarly, as a result of the previous point, `pId=2` no longer has a match for its join and is excluded.
- Conversely, `left outer join` means the left hand side doesn't need a match. As a result the row is included, but because there is no matching row in table3, those values are returned as NULL.
- Also note that 2 rows in table 3 match the same row in table2. As a result, both rows in table3 are returned and the matching data from table1 and table2 is duplicated to both rows.